# What is the maximum speed per hours or miles per hour i will be able to hit on a straight? Read description, please help

Tags: automotive-engineering

I have a go kart project and this is what I'm trying to do. The kart also has 28-8 tires in the back.I have a 6.5hp motor that can run at max torque at 2500rpm. I need it to move 400 to 500 pounds. With the gearing of a 30 teeth sprocket on the shaft and a 28 teeth sprocket in the rear,

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! Your post ends with a comma and it feels like you might've wanted to put more information there. Is that so? If so, please [edit] your question.

Comment: Your max speed will be when all the motor power is absorbed by the losses, such as gear train, rolling resistance and air resistance. Once you quantify them you can get an idea.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar carts professionally manufactured with similar engines go up to 40-45 mph.

At the final analysis, your engine has to deal with two factors both friction type.

One is the friction loss through your drivetrain.

The other is drag forces induced by the stream of air you go through.

the second one is easier to analyze.

the well-known equation is:

$Fd = 1/2C_d  ρ v^2 A $

- Fd is the drag force in Newtons.
- Cd is the drag factor which for open carts with the rider is roughly 1.2-1.4.
- $ \rho$ is the air density which is approximate $1.2kgm^3$.
- $ v$ is the speed of the car m/s.
- A is the total surface area of the rider on the cart$ m^2$.

you could estimate it by taking a photo from 40 feet away of the cart set in front of a scaled black and white checkered cardboard background, similar to the formula one racing flag.
The first part is all up to your design and quality of the parts you use, your experience in design.

Comment: and to get the total rolling resistance in each gear you could pull the cart using a set of spring scales...